# How do I install drivers for windows 8.1 on motherboard with windows 7 support

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, motherboard

I have installed windows 8.1 pro on my pc. After installing I noticed that audio is not working also every thing on screen looks zoomed in. I realized that the drivers on my motherboard support till windows 7. My motherboard is [Intel D102GGC2](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/22752/Intel-Desktop-Board-D102GGC2). Please help me installing drivers especially the audio one..

Comment: If the drivers for your device on Windows Update, do not provide working audio, it's very unlikely the Windows 7 audio drivers are actually going to work.

Answer (score 0):

By getting Windows 8.1 drivers from the manufacturer (check their website). If the Manufacturer doesn't provide Windows 8.1 drivers you simply don't. I'm sorry, but that's just the way it is. You should always verify driver support before upgrading Windows.